# Как найти минимальное значение в списке List С# Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, list

У меня есть список List с элементами типа int в нём. Подскажите как найти минимальное значение элемента в списке.

Я пробовал сделать это вот таким способом, но выводит совсем не то что нужно.

```
public List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 3, 5, 7, 2, 1, 6, 9, 8};

    private void Start()
    {
        int min = numbers[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            if (min > numbers[i])
            {
                min = numbers[i];
            }

            print(min);
        }
    }
```

Comment: print вынесите из цикла

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте импорт `System.Linq` и сможете использовать метод [Min](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.min?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0)

Пример:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 3, 5, 7, 2, 1, 6, 9, 8};
        Console.WriteLine("min: " + numbers.Min());
    }
}
```